# Finding $f(k)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)\neq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does there exists $f(k)$ function such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$$
diverges but
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$$
converges.

Or

Find $f(k)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)\neq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$

Sorry for my English. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$? You always have to specify in what sense the sum is infinite, and in a typical real analysis course, the infinite sum is _defined_ as the limit of partial sums

Comment: @vito we usually define the infinite sum as the limit of the partial sums... So no

Comment: @charlestoncrabb I'm curious now what other ways might one define it.

Comment: Limits always depend on the topology of the space, so the infinite limit could have any number of meanings depending on the space $f(k)$ takes values in, the topology on that space, etc.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss there is function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges but $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-t}^{t}f(x)dx$ converges.  An improper integral is the limit of a definite integral?

Comment: @vito not quite.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss is right. The first symbol **means** a limit. You can't literally perform an infinite number of additions. You can only perform a finite number of additions to obtain partial sums. The symbol with "$\infty$" as an upper limit really means the limit of the partial sums as the number of terms grows without bound.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss I think this question is same as $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=f(\infty)$ is always true for any $f(x) $? for example $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ . $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\neq f(1)$

Comment: @vito my point is that it really depends on your definition of the integral. I would suggest you investigate the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in both the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals.

Answer (score 3):

No; these are the same thing.

In particular, we define "improper" sums like this AS the limit of partial sums as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you have seen most people interpret $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$$  not as something to be determined but as a *definition*.

But there is another popular way to define an infinite sum that is different and, for that definition, you can indeed ask whether the two sums are the same.

Define the *unordered sum* $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb N} f(k) = S$$
to mean that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite set $F_0\subset 
\mathbb N$ with the property that for any finite set $F_0 \subset F\subset \mathbb N$ the inequality 
 $$\left| \sum_{k\in   F} f(k) - S\right|< \epsilon $$ holds.

Now ask your question using this definition and using this other terminology that won't conflict with the usual terminology:

> Does there exists a function $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ so that
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) $$ exists but $$\sum_{k\in
>   \mathbb N} f(k)  $$ does not?